# Fake names detection

Tags: python

I have a list of users. Each user has First name and Last name fields. Most of user details are accurate. From time to time, I can see users that signed up using fake details.

For example:

- Valid: Alon Mask
- In valid: Asd Dfds

I'm looking to find a way to check if name is legitim or not. What is the best approach to solve it?

My development stack is Python.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: Share your tries first and we'll help if you have a specific problem ;)

Comment: Huh, what is legit name?

Comment: Not sure how you could hope to determine that "Asd Dfds" is a fake name. "Dfds" looks pretty unlikely, but "Asd" could be a real name. At least as feasible as "Alon Mask". You're better off not telling people their names aren't real just because they don't look like you expect names to look.

Comment: I would think if you want to detect fake users, checking whether they gave a valid email would be a better bet

Comment: 40 facts about names you may think are right ... but ain't:  https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Don't be the programmer who makes life difficult for others: "Using a single-letter surname may cause various bureaucratic and social difficulties, as many computer programs cannot deal with such names because they are designed to require a minimum of two or three letters, while people may assume that a single letter is only an abbreviation rather than the complete surname; in 1991, The New York Times wrote an article about one Korean American man surnamed O who ended up changing the spelling of his name to Oh to get around these problems."

Answer (score 2):

You can use the google cloude infotype API to extrat types of info from a given string

https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/quickstart-json

It works by sending a Json request to the API which will return the info you're looking for with minimum likelihood.

Example with phone number:

```
{
  "item":{
    "value":"My phone number is (206) 555-0123."
  },
  "inspectConfig":{
    "infoTypes":[
      {
        "name":"PHONE_NUMBER"
      },
      {
        "name":"US_TOLLFREE_PHONE_NUMBER"
      }
    ],
    "minLikelihood":"POSSIBLE",
    "limits":{
      "maxFindingsPerItem":0
    },
    "includeQuote":true
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "result":{
    "findings":[
      {
        "quote":"(206) 555-0123",
        "infoType":{
          "name":"PHONE_NUMBER"
        },
        "likelihood":"LIKELY",
        "location":{
          "byteRange":{
            "start":"19",
            "end":"33"
          },
          "codepointRange":{
            "start":"19",
            "end":"33"
          }
        },
        "createTime":"2018-11-30T01:01:30.883Z"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/infotypes-reference#global has all the infotypes, you probably want experiment with those:

PERSON_NAME
A full person name, which can include first names, middle names or initials, and last names. Note: Not recommended for use during latency sensitive operations.

FIRST_NAME
A first name is defined as the first part of a PERSON_NAME. Note: Not recommended for use during latency sensitive operations.

LAST_NAME
A last name is defined as the last part of a PERSON_NAME.
Note: Not recommended for use during latency sensitive operations.